# increment value by one jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to increment values by 1, when I click buttons then it is get value by input hidden and show in console. like click button `add1` it is pick the value 5 and show in console and vice versa. now I want to increment value by 1 to click every button get value and increment. like click `add1` and show 5 in console when I click again `add1` button it os increment by 1 and show 6 and so on. any suggestion how do this?

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '.add', function(e) {

    var $parent = $(this).closest('.vote');
    var _vote = parseInt($parent.find('#_vote').val());
    console.log(_vote);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="vote">
    <button class="add">add1</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_vote" id="_vote" value="5">
  </div>

  <div class="vote">
    <button class="add">add2</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_vote" id="_vote" value="10">
  </div>

  <div class="vote">
    <button class="add">add3</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_vote" id="_vote" value="15">
  </div>
```

Comment: A little bit unclear what are you asking, But you want this? `console.log(_vote + 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just **set the new incremented value** to the same element

```
    $parent.find('#_vote').val( _vote + 1 );
```

**Demo**

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '.add', function(e) {

    var $parent = $(this).closest('.vote');
    var _vote = parseInt($parent.find('#_vote').val());
    console.log(_vote);
    $parent.find('#_vote').val( _vote + 1 ); //this line has been added
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="vote">
    <button class="add">add1</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_vote" id="_vote" value="5">
  </div>

  <div class="vote">
    <button class="add">add2</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_vote" id="_vote" value="10">
  </div>

  <div class="vote">
    <button class="add">add3</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_vote" id="_vote" value="15">
  </div>
```

**Note**

- Its a good idea to save the `$parent.find('#_vote')`, just like you did for `$parent` into a variable so that you don't have to fetch it again.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Though it is unclear to me why didn't you tried it out yourself since you were already using `val` method for getting the value and you just had to use `val` for setting an incremented value.

Answer (score 2):

On each click you can increase the value by one and set it back to the value of the input field. I would suggest you to store the input element in a variable so that you wont have to fetch that again and again.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '.add', function(e) {

    var $el = $(this).closest('.vote').find('#_vote')
    var _vote = +$el.val();
    console.log(_vote);
    $el.val(_vote + 1);


  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="vote">
    <button class="add">add1</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_vote" id="_vote" value="5">
  </div>

  <div class="vote">
    <button class="add">add2</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_vote" id="_vote" value="10">
  </div>

  <div class="vote">
    <button class="add">add3</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_vote" id="_vote" value="15">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

get hidden value and increment it by one and then store this value in hidden field.

```
        var $parent = $(this).closest('.vote');
        var _vote = parseInt($parent.find('#_vote').val());
        console.log(_vote);
        $parent.val(parseInt(_vote)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `each` loop then define `i` by `0` then increment `i` with `i++` when click. *In other word*, you plus your current `value` with `0` then after second click `i` increment by `i++` then it plus current `value` with `1`.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.add').each(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $(this).on('click', function(e) {
      var $parent = $(this).closest('.vote');
      var _vote = parseInt($parent.find('#_vote').val());
      console.log(_vote + i++);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="vote">
    <button class="add">add1</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_vote" id="_vote" value="5">
  </div>

  <div class="vote">
    <button class="add">add2</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_vote" id="_vote" value="10">
  </div>

  <div class="vote">
    <button class="add">add3</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_vote" id="_vote" value="15">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this jQuery function.

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '.add', function(e) {
    var $parent = $(this).closest('.vote');
    var _vote = parseInt($parent.find('#_vote').val());
    var test = _vote + parseInt(1);

    var $parentId = $(this).closest('.vote');
    var _voteId = $parent.find('#_vote');

    _voteId.val(test);

    console.log(_vote);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like Below.

Just add below two lines in your Jquery code

```
var _vote = parseInt($parent.find('#_vote').val()) + 1;
$parent.find('#_vote').val(_vote)
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '.add', function(e) {

    var $parent = $(this).closest('.vote');
    var _vote = parseInt($parent.find('#_vote').val()) + 1;
    $parent.find('#_vote').val(_vote)
    console.log(_vote);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="vote">
    <button class="add">add1</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_vote" id="_vote" value="5">
  </div>

  <div class="vote">
    <button class="add">add2</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_vote" id="_vote" value="10">
  </div>

  <div class="vote">
    <button class="add">add3</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_vote" id="_vote" value="15">
  </div>
```